# Trigonometry question proof

Tags: trigonometry

> If $0 < a$, $b < \pi$ , $\cos a + \cos b - \cos ( a + b) = 3/2 $, 
>   then show that  
>   $a = b=  \pi/3$
>   
>  I tried expanding $cos(a+b)$ but what to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula & $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$,
 $$\dfrac32=2\cos\dfrac{A+B}2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2-\left(2\cos^2\dfrac{A+B}2-1\right)$$

Rearrange to form a Quadratic Equation in $\cos\dfrac{A+B}2$

As $\cos\dfrac{A+B}2$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

Comment: Why should cos (A+B)/2 be real?

Comment: @JamilAhmed, We are dealing with real Triangle, right?

Comment: We are dealing with any angle on the co-ordinate plane. So should that mean the angle should be real?

Comment: Are you saying you do not know what an **angle** *is*?

Comment: @user247327, $$0<a,b<\pi\implies a,b$$ are real , so will be $$\cos\dfrac{A+B}2$$